# How not to proceed to the next elif if the first is true?

Tags: bash, shell-script, control-flow

I have a list of text files in a directory which I want to search from terminal. To not make myself think too much, I want to be able to search for few words, example `search one two three` if there is a file that has one of more of those words in its name, return it. This is the if statements I have:

```
snip-list() {
    for filename in ~/notes/*; do
        file=`basename "$filename"`
        fs=${file%.*}
        if [[ $fs =~ $1 ]] && [[ $fs =~ $2 ]] && [[ $fs =~ $3 ]] && [[ $fs =~ $4 ]] && [[ $fs =~ $5 ]]; then
            echo $fs
            # exit
        elif [[ $fs =~ $1 ]] && [[ $fs =~ $2 ]] && [[ $fs =~ $3 ]] && [[ $fs =~ $4 ]]; then
            echo $fs
            # exit
        elif [[ $fs =~ $1 ]] && [[ $fs =~ $2 ]] && [[ $fs =~ $3 ]]; then
            echo $fs
            # exit
        elif [[ $fs =~ $1 ]] && [[ $fs =~ $2 ]]; then
            echo $fs
            # exit
        elif [[ $fs =~ $1 ]]; then
            echo $fs
        fi
    done
}
```

I'll be adding files to this directory, so if I run that statement as is, I'll get so many returned that it be useless (at least I'd have to scroll to the top to see the first results).

If there a way to make it so that "if user searched 5 terms and they return something, **don't run the other 4 conditions**

I have tried running `exit` after each statement, that's the kind of thing I want by **I need the terminal window to stay open.**

Comment: 1) That's what `elif` is for ("else if"). 2) `exit` doesn't close the terminal window. Can you [edit] your question with a *complete* code sample, more detail of what you're trying, what your directory looks like, and how you're running this?

Comment: @MichaelHomer I added the entire function. If I remove the comment from exit, the if statement quickly returns and then the window closes

Comment: are you running that function from a shell command line?  BTW, use `return` rather than `exit` to return from a shell function.  if using `bash`, type `help return` for details. otherwise, see your shell's man page.

Comment: I guess you want `return`. You are getting the behaviour you want of "if the user searched 5 terms and they return something, don't run the other 4 conditions". It's when they **don't** all match that you're having a problem.

Comment: @MichaelHomer that sounds correct and `help return` says the same thing but it's not working! Would the file type matter? I have the script in a .bashrc file and then added this line `. ~/my_bash_scripts/my-codes.bashrc` inside `~/.bashrc` file. And every time I make changes, I source the main file `. ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `return` rather than `exit` to return from a shell function.

If you're using `bash` or some other shell with built-in help, type `help return` for details. Otherwise, see your shell's man page.

Comment: Thanks. That seems right `bash help` says "[return] Causes a function to exit", but is not working. This is my first time working with bash, would the file type matter? I have the script in a `.bashrc` file and then added this line `. ~/my_bash_scripts/my-codes.bashrc` inside `~/.bashrc` file. And every time I make changes, I source the main file  `. ~/.bashrc`

Comment: Nope, file type doesn't matter (aside from executable binaries and `#!` lines in scripts you execute rather than source, linux/unix itself doesn't really have any concept of file types.  Desktop environments or GUI file browsers may distinguish between file "types" but the shell doesn't), as long as it contains only valid shell commands and can be sourced.  what exactly do you mean by "is not working"?  `return` works exactly as specified in the help and in the man page, i've used it many times.

Comment: I have no idea why it didn't work, I typed a string rather than used a variable and it worked. Then went back to use of variables and it works. Thanks

Comment: BTW, you do realise that your `if` lines with two or more tests are ANDed? they'll only echo $fs if $fs matches ALL of the tests.  i.e. what you have won't match filenames that match $2 but not $1 (but will match filenames that match $1 alone).   Are you sure you don't want OR instead?  if so, use `if [[ $fs =~ $1|$2|$3|$4|$5 ]] ; then ... fi`.  An alternative would be to test `$fs` against `$1`...`$5` in a loop, incrementing a counter if it matches.  echo `$fs` and return if the counter is non-zero...you could even return the counter value in the return statement or in the echo statement.

Comment: That's what I realised after fixing the return statement. I saw this comment late. I ended up using this `if [[ $fs =~ .*$1*.* ]]; then` for the moment. The loop sounds good but I have to search how to go that. I'm try to do this: I say I have a file name `one-two-three-four-five' and one called `one-two` if I type `one-two` I don't want the first to display. But for now I have no idea. I thought the ifs I had would do the trick but they don't. This `if [[ $fs =~ .*$1*.* ]]; then` works best - which what I had 10 hours ago :)

Comment: You really need to learn a LOT more about regular expressions.  There are a lot of good questions and answers on the topic on this site.  I've added the `/regular-expression` tag to your question, click on it to get a list of questions with that tag.  Also search for questions involving `grep`, `sed`, `awk`, or `perl`, amongst others.